# How to select in mysql with 2 times WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with destionations PRN, SKP, MUC etc.

I want to select 15 rows with the destionation PRN and SKP, but I am not sure how to do this because when I write down

```
SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE date >= NOW() AND destination = 'PRN' OR 'SKP'
```

it wont work it will show only where SKP or only where PRN, I have tried this with OR, AND adn so on.. but I cant a way that works and selects 15 last destinations where destionation = PRN and SKP.

Comment: Do you want 15 of each destination or 15 total rows of either?

Comment: Please show us a few rows of your table with data.

Comment: Ok thank you everyone I found a solutions for this because it had another problem. so I would like to thank you all for your help. I think I am going to use your examples some other time.

thank you for your time and help

Comment: Please have a look at our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use as :

```
SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE date >= NOW() AND (destination = 'PRN' OR destination = 'SKP')
```

or use IN operator

```
SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE date >= NOW() AND destination IN ('PRN','SKP')
```

and for only 15 row you can add " `LIMIT 15"` after query

Comment: I would add parentheses to make it abundantly clear what rules are being applied, but that's just me.

Comment: Need to add some parentheses to get the AND/OR order of precedence correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE date >= NOW() 
AND (destination = 'PRN' OR destination='SKP')
ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE date >= NOW() AND destination IN ('PRN', 'SPK')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE date >= NOW() AND (destination = 'PRN' OR destination =  'SPK')
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Using in is generally the most readable form (especially if you have multiple destinations):

```
SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE date >= NOW() AND destination IN ( 'PRN' , 'SKP' )
```

When using or,  be sure to put brackets around the second term so its clear which operator is applied first:

```
SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE date >= NOW() AND (destination = 'PRN' OR destination = 'SPK')
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE date >= NOW() AND (destination = 'PRN' OR destination = 'SKP')
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE date >= NOW() AND destination IN ('PRN', 'SKP')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE date >= NOW() AND destination IN ('PRN' , 'SKP')
```